# Place '~' symbol as overarrow

Tags: accents

I would like to know how to place `~` or `-` on top of a character. I believe I could do this with the `\overrightarrow{character}` command for right arrows. But how do I do this in general?

Comment: Also consider the [`accents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/accents).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both of these particular symbols can be placed over characters using accents. For a full reference, see [this Latex wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Accents).

In math mode, you would use `$\tilde{x}$` for x with a ~ on top, and `$\bar{x}$` for x with a bar on top. If you would like the tilde or bar to span multiple characters, you can instead use `$\widetilde{xy}$` or `$\overline{xy}`.

In text mode, you could use `\~{x}` and `\={x}` to get these accents over those characters.